# How to port Excel VBA macro to OpenOffice macro?

Tags: vba, excel, openoffice.org

How to port Excel VBA macro to OpenOffice macro?

Here is macro for creating hyperlinks:

```
Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim r As Range
    Dq = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Dq & "http://" & r.Text & Dq & ";" & Dq & r.Text & Dq & ")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

I tried convert this macro to OpenOffice macro (using http://www.business-spreadsheets.com/vba2oo.asp)

```
Sub HyperMaker()
Dim r As Dim oSheet as Object[n]oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet[n]oSheet.getCellRangeByName($1)
Dq = Chr(34)
For Each r In Selection
r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Dq & "http://" & r.Text & Dq & ";" & Dq & r.Text & Dq & ")"
Next r
End Sub
```

But got errors: `BASIC syntax error: Unexpected symbol: Dim.` , `Expected:,.`

Replacing Dim with comma not help.
How to make it work in OpenOfffice?

Comment: I have no clue how OpenOffice macros are different from VBA but `Dim r as ` is missing type? `Range` doesn't seem to be recognizable data type by the converter you've used so try `Dim r as Variant` instead.

Comment: Right, I dont have OpenOffice so I can't really help you out on this one. Maybe someone else will show up and rescue you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

```
Sub makeHyperlinks()
    Dim sh As Object, z As Object, c As Object
    Dim qCells As Object, enuCells As Object
    sh = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("YourSheetName")
    z = sh.getCellRangeByName("B1:B5") ' your column (or rectangle)
    qCells = z.queryContentCells(-1)
    enuCells = qCells.Cells.createEnumeration
    Do While enuCells.hasMoreElements
      c = enuCells.nextElement
      c.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""http://" & c.String & """)"
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What caused your problem, could you explain a little?

Comment: OpenOffice have limited support for VBA macros, it doesn’t support all VBA features.
There exists fundamental differences to the way the code is constructed in OpenOffice Basic compared with Visual Basic for Applications. Excel VBA code is not the equivalent to OpenOffice Calc Basic script.